# Memory size of a String Array storing binary codes

Tags: java, string, binary

I want to store a list of binary codes in a String[] array, such as in the following example...

```
String[] str={"10001", "100101","101010101"};
```

How much memory is required to store the array?

Comment: If your question has been answered, or if it is no longer valid, please 'tick' to choose the most appropriate answer so everyone knows that the problem has been resolved. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will find [here](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/memory/string_memory_usage.shtml) the following result:

> Minimum String memory usage (bytes) = 8 * (int) ((((no chars) * 2) + 45) / 8)

Comment: umm, I am not sure what `45` represents.

Comment: All kinds of housekeeping data, like the reference to the char-array; lengths, etc.

Comment: If you use `-XX:+UseCompressedStrings` which is on by default in some Java 6 updates, it can use one byte per character.

Comment: As you can read in the linked article, the quoted formula is just half the story. In any case, the required memory is highly dependent on the implementation of the VM, so it is impossible to give an exact answer.

Comment: @jarnbjo: quite correct.  An interesting article, but the above gives some guideline at least.  I found the fact that substrings can take more than the above quite interesting (read sad).

Comment: @Jaco: Why is that sad? For exactly the same reason, substrings can also use less memory.

Comment: well I am doing college project in image compression. If I am applying any algorithm to reduce the number of bits then which data structure/ variable array should I use to store the processed binary values? int array will consider them as integer than binary values. what about string? will the number of bits will occupy the same size as the length of string?

Comment: Are you storing the image back to disk? ...or in memory?  In either case, a String should not be used for this purpose. Rather use a byte array for that purpose.  You can still address each bit if you really want to.  Which compressions techniques are you using?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store this data more efficiently, you would be best to store it in a numerical array, such as `int[]`. By using a `String[]` array, each character uses at least 2 byte of memory, (for example, 1010 would use a minimum of 8 bytes of memory), whereas storing the value in an `int[]` array allows you to store much larger binary numbers without adding extra bytes.

For a simple comparison, a single `int` is 4 bytes. If you store the binary value of an `int` as a `String`, it will use 64 bytes (as there are 32 bits in 4 bytes, and each 'bit' is stored as a unicode character of 2 bytes length).

Comment: i didnt get the last para. well I am doing college project in image compression. If I am applying any algorithm to reduce the number of bits then which data structure/ variable array should I use to store the processed binary values?

Comment: For compression, you would want to store the binary values as individual bits. To do this, you want to combine 8 binary values (bits) into a single byte, which can then be stored in a data structure or file (bytes are the smallest usable/practical data components in modern computers and programming languages). Get 8 bits, work out what that represents as a decimal number, and then store that as a (byte)number;